# SCRAPY not printing all the items in the terminal

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash, scrapy-shell

I am using this command in the terminal using SCRAPY Shell but it's not printing all the items.

```
scrapy shell https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2017:0621

response.xpath('normalize-space((//div[contains(@class, "tab-pane")]/ul)[2]/li/text())').getall()
```

**It just prints the first item.**

Comment: Your xpath only matches one element on that page. What is the result you were expecting to get?

Comment: The XPath shows 1 of 8 items. I want to get all 8 items.

Answer (score 1):

`normalize-space()` only works with a single node. If you give it a nodeset, it will return the value produced from the first node.

If you want to apply it to multiple nodes, you can do that as follows (`pp` is just a pretty-printing function):

```
>>> products = response.xpath('(//div[contains(@class, "tab-pane")]/ul)[2]/li').xpath('normalize-space()').getall()
>>> pp(products)
[
    'Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 6 x86_64',
    'Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 6 i386',
    'Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation 6 x86_64',
    'Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation 6 i386',
    'Red Hat Enterprise Linux Desktop 6 x86_64',
    'Red Hat Enterprise Linux Desktop 6 i386',
    'Red Hat Enterprise Linux for Power, big endian 6 ppc64',
    'Red Hat Enterprise Linux for Scientific Computing 6 x86_64'
]
```